# Slideshow Troubleshooting (Timer & Animation)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, slideshow

I am trying to create a slideshow completely from scratch using html, css and plain javascript but I can't figure out what to do so that when I click one of the slideshow indicators the setInterval() resets its timer (in order to be able to change slide without it directly switching to the next one because there is, for example, only 1 sec left)

I have tried to reset the timer with clearInterval() and then reactivating the setInterval() but when I then click on one of the slideshow indicators the slides start changing at random moments (they don't follow the 6000ms timer of the SetInterval() for some reason).

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
var dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");

function removeClass() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
}

function removeNext() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove('next');
  }
}

function slideshow() {
    currentSlide = document.querySelector(".active");
    nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextSlide != null) {
        removeClass();
        nextSlide.classList.add('next');
        nextSlide.classList.add('active');
    } else {
        removeClass();
        slides[0].classList.add('next');
        slides[0].classList.add('active');
    }
    removeNext();
}

var slideDelay = setInterval(slideshow, 6000);

document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if (event.target.className == "dot") {
        removeClass();
        var dotAttrValue = event.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to');
        slides[dotAttrValue-1].classList.add('active');
        clearInterval(slideDelay);  
        var slideDelay = setInterval(slideshow, 6000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try taking out the second "var" before slideDelay. You may be creating two separate variables called slideDelay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having two var declarations creates two separate intervals. Just get rid of the second one and you should be good to go.

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
var dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");

function removeClass() {
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
}

function removeNext() {
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].classList.remove('next');
    }
}

function slideshow() {
    currentSlide = document.querySelector(".active");
    nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextSlide != null) {
        removeClass();
        nextSlide.classList.add('next');
        nextSlide.classList.add('active');
    } else {
        removeClass();
        slides[0].classList.add('next');
        slides[0].classList.add('active');
    }
    removeNext();
}

var slideDelay = setInterval(slideshow, 6000);

document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.className == "dot") {
        removeClass();
        var dotAttrValue = event.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to');
        slides[dotAttrValue - 1].classList.add('active');
        clearInterval(slideDelay);
        slideDelay = setInterval(slideshow, 6000);//Var removed from here.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! This fixed the problem with the interval.

Comment: No problem, do you mind marking this question as solved.